# Auto mapper always spliting each character when supposed to split by ','

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have a string property that I am trying to split by ','

below is the code for the mapping

```cs
CreateMap<eCenterService.Domain.StudentExamPreparation, StudentExamPreparationDto>()
    .ForMember(
        des => des.DoesTheStudentPlanToTakeExam,
        m => m.MapFrom(src => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(src.DoesTheStudentPlanToTakeExam)
            ? src.DoesTheStudentPlanToTakeExam
                .Split(new char[','], System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            : null));
```

I am tring to get something like :

> "doesTheStudentPlanToTakeExam": [
> "SAT",
> "UNDECIDED"
> ]

but what I keep getting is:

> "doesTheStudentPlanToTakeExam": [
> "S",
> "A",
> "T",
> ",",
> " ",
> "U",
> "N",
> "D",
> "E",
> "C",
> "I",
> "D",
> "E",
> "D"
> ]

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please add a [mre].

Answer (score 3):

`new char[',']` due to built-in [implicit conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/char#conversions) is actually an empty array of chars with size of 44 ([`new char[44]`](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCDMACciDCiDetE+UkALIgLIAUAlJtrjQG4CGATogB6IC8iAdgKYDuiAMYALJgG0A5ABoJAXQDc1HAF9YyoA==), `(int)',' == 44`).

Change the separator from  `new char[',']` either to just `','` or to `new char[]{',', ' '}` (based on your data and requirements):

```cs
CreateMap<StudentExamPreparation, StudentExamPreparationDto>()
    .ForMember(des => des.DoesTheStudentPlanToTakeExam,
        m => m.MapFrom(src =>
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(src.DoesTheStudentPlanToTakeExam)
                ? src.DoesTheStudentPlanToTakeExam.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                : null));
```

Comment: @YongShun based on output and desired output OP needs to remove spaces also which can be achieved by adding space to split characters. Though it actually depends on data if this is a good approach.

Comment: Haha nice catch and what a mean syntax quirk! :D